# Добавлять класс только тогда, когда видим объект. Как? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно нужно сделать анимацию чтобы она была каждый раз когда объект попадает в поле видимости. То есть если я вижу объект - добавляется класс или выполняется любое другое действие через jQuery.

Как сделать такую проверку ?

Comment: Ставить хэндлер на каждое событие, которое меняет его видимость. Либо при вызове необходимых функций чекать его видимость. Ничего необычного.

Comment: А можете привести пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: А вот в ответах как раз уже его привели. '=)'

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, видимость на конкретном скроле страницы?

Comment: Наверное. Мне нужно анимировать объект тогда, когда мы его видим. Чтобы каждый раз выполнялось действие, когда он попадает в зону видимости.

Comment: То есть как только мы доскрулили до элемента, выполняется действие.

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет?

```
var obj = $([селектор-обекта]);
if (obj.is(':visible')) {
    obj.addClass('visible');
} else {
    obj.removeClass('visible');
}
```

Comment: Это работает только один раз. А как сделать так, чтобы каждый раз, когда объект был в зоне видимости, выполнялось действие?

Comment: Ну значит сделайте так, чтобы класс удалялся, если объект не видим. Исправил ответ